# Why can a partition be a refinement of itself?

Tags: real-analysis, partitions-for-integration

Generally speaking, to call something a ‘refinement’ has certain implications. For instance, intuitively if one were to refine a partition of some interval it would make sense that the Darboux sums of the refinement would provide a better estimation of the integral than the original partition.

With this in mind, what is the benefit of including the partition itself in the set of its refinements?

Comment: This is equivalent to the question *What is the benefit of using weak inequalities $\leq$ instead of strong ones $<$?* (or $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$). There are lots of situations where your statements are cleaner if you allow for "no change" when passing from one object to the next.

Comment: Addressing your statement about intuition, just imagine that a *better* estimation of the integral is just one that is *not worse!*

Comment: Most likely if we didn't allow it then a bunch of proofs would get more complicated, having to deal separately with the possibility that some partition that was constructed out of other partitions might just be the "trivial" refinement. And, it doesn't complicate any other proofs. So, in a word: convenience.

Comment: Say we partition the interval $[0,1]$ as $[0,1/2),[1/2,1]$ but then ignore the refinement and take our next partition to be $[0,1/3),[1/3,2/3),[2/3,1]$. Can you scheme up a function where that makes the Darboux sum a worse estimate of the integral? Just think about the graph for a bit.